# How to add gyrator in a circuit using circuitikz?

Tags: circuitikz

How do you add elements like resistor in a circuit that has a gyrator?

[image: Circuit with gyrator and transformer]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Can you provide a picture for people that are not familiar with circuits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved in two ways using either tikz with circuit library or circuitikz.

**a.** Using tikz with circuit library:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC}
\usepackage[european resistor,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % input arrow and its current symbol
        \draw (0.3,2.1) node[inputarrow]{} 
                    node[above]{i\textsubscript{s}};
        % leftmost circuit
        \draw (0,2.1) node[ocirc]{} % gyrator height is 2.1 unit
            to [R,l=R\textsubscript{E}] (2,2.1)
            to [L,l=L$_\text{E}$](4,2.1);
        \draw (0,0) node[ocirc]{} to (4,0);
        % gyrator node
        \draw (5,2.1) node[gyrator]{}
                     node[above]{T};
        % middle circuit elements
        \draw (6.1,2.1) node[inputarrow]{} 
                    node[above]{v\textsubscript{c}};
        \draw (6,2.1)
            to [R,l=R\textsubscript{MS}, i=] (8,2.1)
            to [L,l=M$_\text{MS}$]  (10,2.1)
            to [C,l=C\textsubscript{MS}] (12,2.1);
        \draw (12,0) to (6,0);
        % rightmost circuit
        \draw (13,2.1) node[transformer]{}
            node[above]{S\textsubscript{S}:1};
        \draw (14,2.1) to (15,2.1) node[ocirc]{};
        \draw (14,0) to (15,0) node[ocirc]{};
        % output current
        \draw (14.5,2.1) node[inputarrow]{} 
                    node[above]{Q\textsubscript{s}};
        % input output levels
        \draw[->] (0,1.4) to node[right]{u\textsubscript{s}} (0,0.6);
        \draw[->] (15,1.4) to node[left]{P\textsubscript{s}} (15,0.6);          
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**b.** Using circuitikz:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage[european resistor,siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        % input arrow and its current symbol
        \draw (0.3,2.1) node[inputarrow]{} 
                    node[above]{i\textsubscript{s}};
        % leftmost circuit
        \draw (0,2.1) node[ocirc]{} % gyrator height is 2.1 unit
            to [R,l=R\textsubscript{E}] (2,2.1)
            to [L,l=L$_\text{E}$](4,2.1);
        \draw (0,0) node[ocirc]{} to (4,0);
        % gyrator node
        \draw (5,2.1) node[gyrator]{}
                     node[above]{T};
        % middle circuit elements
        \draw (6.1,2.1) node[inputarrow]{} 
                    node[above]{v\textsubscript{c}};
        \draw (6,2.1)
            to [R,l=R\textsubscript{MS}, i=] (8,2.1)
            to [L,l=M$_\text{MS}$]  (10,2.1)
            to [C,l=C\textsubscript{MS}] (12,2.1);
        \draw (12,0) to (6,0);
        % rightmost circuit
        \draw (13,2.1) node[transformer]{}
            node[above]{S\textsubscript{S}:1};
        \draw (14,2.1) to (15,2.1) node[ocirc]{};
        \draw (14,0) to (15,0) node[ocirc]{};
        % output current
        \draw (14.5,2.1) node[inputarrow]{} 
                    node[above]{Q\textsubscript{s}};
        % input output levels
        \draw[->] (0,1.4) to node[right]{u\textsubscript{s}} (0,0.6);
        \draw[->] (15,1.4) to node[left]{P\textsubscript{s}} (15,0.6);          
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Both result same output:

[image]

Comment: This is great can you please explain how the node thing works when using the gyrator or transformer?

Comment: Actually I connected initially, say, gyrator at the end of the inductor at (4,2.1). But its pin overlapped with that of inductor. Thus, extended 1 point further at (5,2.1). It solves the issue. So does for transformer! Use the same logic for gyrator/transformer height also [kind of hit and trial method] :-) !

Comment: Hmmm are you talking about the double node command I used for gyrator/transformer??? That's self explained I guess, first node is for the circuit element while the second one is for device label :-D